# How to show no analytic function with absolute value greater than negative power of absolute value z?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am taking an exam tomorrow on Complex Analysis, and this is a problem I have come across multiple times on old exams and I've been stumped.

"Show that there is no function f analytic on the punctured plane $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ that satisfies $$|f(z)| \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}} \,\,\, \forall z \neq 0."$$

I probably tried a number of things back in June when I first saw it, but can't find my work on that right now. When I was going through again today, my initial approach was to assume by contradiction that there is such an f. I set $g(z)=f(1/z)$. Then g would have a pole at infinity. Bringing that information back to f, there's a pole at 0. Which I probably should have seen before doing that.

Then there's an entire function h and some integer n such that $f(z)=\frac{h(z)}{z^n}$. Right? So I was playing with h. From the inequality, $|h(z)| \ge |z|^{n-1/2}$. That doesn't look like a contradiction to me, but maybe I'm missing something.

I asked somebody who has passed this exam before, and they suggested setting $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$. That gives the inequality $|g(z)| \le \sqrt{|z|}$. Again, I look at singularities. Here, the only singularity is at infinity, the same as my other g. I feel like it's just giving the same information as my first attempt, and I am still seeing no contradiction.

I attempted to search for this on here, but couldn't find a way to formulate it that got me any relevant results through the search bar. If this is a repeat, just point me to the old one and trash mine.

Comment: This isn't a question; it's a statement. Thanks for sharing your experiences with us.

Comment: Even though this isn't a homework question, the points made in [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) still apply. In particular, show your work.

Comment: OK, I finished up what I should have said. Can I get a hint now? I don't want the full answer.

Comment: You can find an answer in the linked duplicate. It's a full answer, but you can stop reading at any point and try to fill in the remaining parts yourself.

Comment: That said, you put good effort into the question, worth an upvote.